# Setting statusBar style does not work Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I am trying to change my statusbar style (the color of status bar text, more specifically) depending on which viewController is active through this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

But that does not work. Rather, it makes the whole navigationBar black (instead of just the statusbar). Neither does the following:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

But this only seems to work when the viewController is not embedded in a navController (when I hide the navBar, it works!). My viewController hierarchy is the following:

tabBarController -> navigationControllers -> viewController

Also: Setting 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to YES & NO does not make a difference.

I am glad for any help!

Comment: `preferredStatusBarStyle` changes the color of the status bar text. `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` will show white text in the status bar. What is the actual result you want?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to happen. Also, it should change between different viewControllers. I have read on other threads that this should not work for VCs within navigationControllers, but the alternative (by setting the navBar style) doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following.
keep this to your ViewController

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{    
    // Add If/else conditions based on which style required on which condition
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Call this code when you want to change the status bar style..

```
[self preferredStatusBarStyle];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Comment: That does not change anything, unfortunately... I put it in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, and viewDidLoad. Nothing worked.

Comment: Can you share some sample code which is not working?